# Answered Question Marked as Duplicate - What should I do?

Tags: discussion, answers, closed-questions

First off I'm sorry if this is a duplicate; I'm using the Android app and I couldn't find any similar questions when searching.

Earlier today I posted this answer which attracted a lot of quick up votes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27547713/1317805.

A couple of hours later the question I'd answered was marked as the duplicate of a question which, despite being asked 2 years ago, only has around 2.5x the number of views this question I answered has already.

I feel that my answer improves upon the answers given in the older question (whose best answer has less than half the votes of my own), but as the answer I've posted is on a closed question people are probably not going to find it in future.

What should I do if I want to keep my contribution relevant?

Comment: Personally, I just walk on and leave my answer under the closed question. I have a few answers like that and they receive upvotes from time to time, so I believe they're still visible. You *may* also flag it for moderator attention and ask for the two questions to be merged, but I'm not sure that's proper etiquette. Don't do that too much, if you do it at all.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote in your question

> I feel that my answer improves upon the answers given in the older question

Then you should add your answer to the original question. That way people don't have to jump between two [duplicate] questions just to see all the answers. The question you answered is marked as a duplicate and therefore has a link to the original question. People will navigate to the original and see your answer there. I prefer seeing all the answers on one Web page rather than having to jump from one to another.

You also wrote:

> best answer has less than half the votes of my own

I would argue that the number of up-votes is not the defining criteria for deciding whether one answer is better than another. Nonetheless, if you feel that your answer is better, then that is another reason to add it to the original question. That also bumps the original question into the "new questions" list – since it has a new answer – and therefore brings it to more people's attention.

So my answer to your question...

> What should I do if I want to keep my contribution relevant?

is to add it to the original question.

Comment: @James Duplicating answers is frowned upon.  So, if you add your A to the linked dup, also delete it from the closed Q. 
A better option _might_ be a Q merge (I'm not familiar with the Q domain,  so can't say if that's appropriate here)